# What is the Test Framework used in asp.net MVC 3 Visualstudio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework

I write test cases using .net framework 4.5 by creating a unit test project.I have to write a report (Brief description (1 page max) of the test framework used.)  how I know what is the test frame work used in Visual studio 2012 when create a test project??

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the references get added to your Unit Test project. You should see
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

This is the MSTest framework.